# Atlas indoor ios example location

Tags: ios, location, indoor-positioning-system

I am using the IndoorAtlas/ios-sdk-examples, but when I run it it seems to get stuck at the waiting for location data. Can someone help me?

Comment: what do you think we are developer or magician. Do you know how stack-overflow works. what have you tried so far ? at-least add some code and effort

Comment: I have followed the github IndoorAtlas SDK2.1 from github, https://github.com/IndoorAtlas/ios-sdk-examples, then I folowed the documentation. Everything works but is keeps on searching for location data, and it is not showing the image on the map.

Answer (score 0):

First check all the API Keys are placed correctly.
then run your application that have downloaded from github on your device.Walk some distance it will trigger the event and load the map.
https://github.com/IndoorAtlas/ios-sdk-examples please download this.